# open virtual switch supporeted platform

Tags: openflow, openvswitch

I heard that it has been ported to multiple virtualization platforms and switching chipsets? what does the virtualization platforms and switching chipsets mean here? what is the difference between them?
another question is :can we install the openvswitch on the bare metal switch or router?I mean can we install it on just hardware without any operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OVS FAQ, which is readily available with a Google search:

#### Q: What virtualization platforms can use Open vSwitch?

A: Open vSwitch can currently run on any Linux-based virtualization
   platform (kernel 2.6.32 and newer), including: KVM, VirtualBox, Xen,
   Xen Cloud Platform, XenServer. As of Linux 3.3 it is part of the
   mainline kernel.  The bulk of the code is written in platform-
   independent C and is easily ported to other environments.  We welcome
   inquires about integrating Open vSwitch with other virtualization
   platforms.

#### Q: How can I try Open vSwitch?

A: The Open vSwitch source code can be built on a Linux system.  You can
   build and experiment with Open vSwitch on any Linux machine.
   Packages for various Linux distributions are available on many
   platforms, including: Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora.

You may also download and run a virtualization platform that already
   has Open vSwitch integrated.  For example, download a recent ISO for
   XenServer or Xen Cloud Platform.  Be aware that the version
   integrated with a particular platform may not be the most recent Open
   vSwitch release.

#### Q: Does Open vSwitch only work on Linux?

A: No, Open vSwitch has been ported to a number of different operating
   systems and hardware platforms.  Most of the development work occurs
   on Linux, but the code should be portable to any POSIX system.  We've
   seen Open vSwitch ported to a number of different platforms,
   including FreeBSD, Windows, and even non-POSIX embedded systems.

By definition, the Open vSwitch Linux kernel module only works on
   Linux and will provide the highest performance.  However, a userspace
   datapath is available that should be very portable.

#### Q: What's involved with porting Open vSwitch to a new platform or switching ASIC?

A: The PORTING document describes how one would go about
   porting Open vSwitch to a new operating system or hardware platform.

- Comparison of virtualzation platforms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software
- Regarding your last question: You need an underlying OS (e.g. Linux)

Comment: @user3201263 please confirm the answer if you find it acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to experiment with sdn , openvswitch and open flow is mininet.
They have a vm you can download and use with virtualbox, vmware etc

http://mininet.org/
http://mininet.org/download

Comment: @Ixx,thank you for your answer, but as I found the mininet is  a tool for just testing and not in real world, so I think the open virtual switch is better ,am I right?

Comment: I think you should go and read those documents ;-) mininet.org  mininet lets you easily script openvswitch and openflow

Comment: ok, I found that the open virtual switch comes preinstalled on the mininet VM , but in general when we can implement the SDN and openflow switch in system by itself so why we should use the ovs in mininet? and another question is, can I implement the ovs without any virtual software, in linux?I mean without for example virtual box or any other virtual thing?(excuse me for some simple questions, I'm new in openflow!)